# FadeOut a div and then refresh (create a random input with php) and then fadeIn the content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have made a box where I fadeout a div, then refresh the div and then fadein the div.
When viewing for a few secounds it starts messing up.

the jQuery

```
setInterval(function(){
    $( "#reclameBlok" ).fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $( "#reclameBlok" ).load("index.php #reclameBlok");
        $( "#reclameBlok" ).fadeIn(5600)
    });
 },9000);
```

the PHP function

```
    public function _getReclameBlok(){
    $HTTP_HOST=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; 
        if($HTTP_HOST!='localhost'){
            //web
            $b='../';
        }else{
            //pc
            $b='';            
        } 

    $db = $this->_conn();
    $sql ="SELECT `producten`.merk, `producten`.type, `producten`.inhoud, `producten`.prijs, `producten`.image FROM `producten` WHERE `rubriek` = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4";            
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $a='';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $a.=    
                        '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center reclameBlokCell">
                        <h2>'.$row['merk'].'</h2> 
                         <h3>'.$row['type'].' '.$row['inhoud'].'</h3>
                        <img src="'.$b.$row['image'].'" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                        <br/>
                        <b>Prijs : '.$row['prijs'].'  €</b>
                        </div>';

        //print_r($row);

    }
    return $a;
}
```

the site -> http://www.mens-hairfashion.be

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see any problem under the "Verkrijgbaar bij ons" section.i keep it running for several minutes, what do you mean "starts messing up"?

Comment: would probably be a lot better to use callbacks of load and animation to trigger next event, not use setInerval

Comment: When I viewed the site with a tablet, its messes up.  It refreshs the div before fading out